# Finding significance levels for cointegrating coefficients in cajorls

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

I am investigating the long-term relationship of some variables using the R package `vars`, but in the output of the `cajorls` function I cannot see whether each coefficient is significant.  This information is provided by the `cajools` function but for the cointegration equations I need to use the `cajorls` function. Does anyone have an idea how to get the information from `cajorls`?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any function or slot within functions in "vars" that allow you to retrieve directly standard errors or p-values for the beta coefficients.

So, in case there is no such thing, you can still use the `blrtest` function that provides a LR test for the beta coefficients. You could test manually:

```
library(vars)
data(finland)
sjf.vecm <- ca.jo(finland, ecdet = "none", type = "eigen", K = 2)

# extract B
B_0 <- cajorls(sjf.vecm, r=1)$beta
# Set one element to zero
B_0[2] <- 0
#test
blrtest(sjf.vecm, H=B_0, r=1)@pval[1]
```

You could use the same strategy to obtain confidence intervals by "profiling" (as is done for `glm`, see `profile.glm`) the LR test:

```
B_0 <- cajorls(sjf.vecm, r=1)$beta
    foo_pval <- function(x) blrtest(sjf.vecm, H=B_0+c(0,x,0,0), r=1)@pval[1]-0.05
    uniroot(foo_pval, interval=c(0,1))$root
```

And don't forget *not* to test for the normalised values, set to one for identification!!

Comment: `blrtest(sjf.vecm, H=B_0, r=1)@pval[1]` produces `8.760424e-07`, and `uniroot(foo_pval, interval=c(0,1))$root` produces `0.2995633`. So, you mean betacoefficient -+ `0.2995633` with p-value=`8.760424e-07`?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the answer is:

The followings are deg. of freedom non-adjusted:

```
coeftest(cajorls(ca.jo(finland, ecdet="none", type="eigen", K=2),r=1)$rlm) 
coef(summary(cajorls(ca.jo(finland, ecdet="none", type="eigen", K=2), r=1)$rlm))
```

The followings are deg. of freedom adjusted:

```
V1.eigen <- ca.jo(finland, ecdet="none", type="eigen", K=2) # rank=1
vecm <- cajorls(V1.eigen, r=1)
beta <- V1.eigen@V[,1] 
alfa <- V1.eigen@W[,1] 
residuals <- resid(vecm$rlm)
N <- nrow(residuals)
sigma <- crossprod(residuals)/N     
beta.se <- sqrt(diag(kronecker(solve(crossprod(V1.eigen@RK[,-1])), solve(t(alfa)%*%solve(sigma) %*% alfa))))
beta.t <- c(NA, beta[-1]/beta.se) # deg.of freedom adjusted
names(beta.t) <- rownames(cajorls(ca.jo(finland, ecdet="none", type="eigen", K=2), r=1)$beta) 
beta.t
beta.pval <- dt(beta.t, df=vecm$rlm$df.residual)
beta.pval
```

Inspiring from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883920/estimating-t-statistics-from-johannsen-cointegration-method-in-ca-jo-in-r), one may suggest (for a neat presentation):

```
library(texreg)
cajo_beta_create <- function(cajo_o, cajorls_o) {
alfa <- coef(cajorls_o$rlm)[1, ]
residuals <- resid(cajorls_o$rlm)
N <- nrow(residuals)
sigma <- crossprod(residuals) / N
beta <- cajorls_o$beta
# standard errors
beta.se <- sqrt(diag(kronecker(solve(crossprod(cajo_o@RK[, -1])), solve(t(alfa) %*% solve(sigma) %*% alfa))))
beta.se2 <- c(NA, beta.se)
beta.t <- c(NA, beta[-1] / beta.se)
beta.pvalue <- dt(beta.t, df=cajorls_o$rlm$df.residual)     # p values

tr <- createTexreg(coef.names = as.character(rownames(beta)), coef = as.numeric(beta), se = beta.se2, pvalues=beta.pvalue,
gof.names = c('Dummy'), gof=c(1), gof.decimal=c(FALSE))
return(tr)
 }
cajo_beta_create(V1.eigen, vecm)
screenreg(cajo_beta_create(V1.eigen, vecm))
```